# Can't view a pandas data frame with a categorical column in spyder variable explorer

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I am using the spyder IDE (version 2.3.4) and pandas (version 0.16.2). I have a dataframe in which one of the columns is of a categorical data type.
I can view regular data frames in the variable explorer with no problem but once I make a column a categorical variable, the variable explorer fails.
Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['type1', 0, 1], ['type2', 2, 3]])
```

Open df now in variable explorer and it works

```
df[0] = df[0].astype('category')
```

Opening df now in variable explorer results in the following error in the spyder internal console:
"ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1"

I don't want to drop the column or change it's type just to be able to view the data frame in the variable explorer.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Or at least whether this is a bug in spyder or pandas?

Comment: This looks like an issue with spyder being unable to understand the dtype, not sure what to suggest here other than calling `print`

Comment: Thanks. I reported the bug to the spyder team.